# How to pass Id to my API request from a selected dropdown in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular8

I am using Angular 6 here i am having one dropdown which is coming from API response.

```
<select 
  class="form-control" 
  name="empName" 
  [(ngModel)]="allData.secondEmp" 
  (change)="typeChange()" 
  (blur)="getid($event)" 
  required
>                           
  <option 
    *ngFor="let employee of Employees" 
    value="{{employee.secondEmp}}">{{employee.firstName}}</option>
</select>
```

Here i am having array like

```
employees = [{id: 1, firstEMp: 'kaushik', secondEmp: 'krishna'}....]
```

Here i want to get id in my request when i change the dropdown function.

I know we need to change the `value="{{employee.id}}"` but i am having some other `*ngIf` conditions here so i cant change `value` here. Any other solution for this? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Template file: use data attribute

```
 <select 
  class="form-control" 
  name="empName" 
  [(ngModel)]="allData.secondEmp" 
  (change)="typeChange()" 
  (blur)="getid($event)" 
  required>                           
  <option 
    *ngFor="let employee of Employees" 
    value="{{employee.secondEmp}}"
    [attr.data-empid] = "employee.id">{{employee.firstName}}</option>
</select>
```

In TS file: get your id

```
getid(e) {
    const targetIndex = e.target;
    const res = targetIndex.options[targetIndex.selectedIndex].dataset.empid;
    console.log(res);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[ngValue] = "{secondEmployee: employee.secondEmp , id: employee.id }"
```

try this

Comment: Its giving me some error like Cannot read property 'secondEmployee' of undefined

Comment: Any alternate solution for this?